# Loop through large .tif stack (image raster) and extract positions

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, raster

I want to run through a large tif stack +1500 frames and extract the coordinates of the local maxima for each frame. The code below does the job, however extremely slow for large files. When running on smaller bits (e.g. 20 frames) each frame is done almost instantly - when running on the whole dataset, each frame takes seconds.

Any solutions to run a faster code? I figure it is due to the loading of the large tiff file - however it should only be necessary one time initially?

[image: My data looks like this - bright dots on a dark background]

I have the following code:

```
from pims import ImageSequence
from skimage.feature import peak_local_max

def cmask(index,array):
  radius = 3
  a,b = index
  nx,ny = array.shape
  y,x = np.ogrid[-a:nx-a,-b:ny-b]
  mask = x*x + y*y <= radius*radius

  return(sum(array[mask])) # number of pixels

images = ImageSequence('tryhard_red_small.tif')


frame_list = []
x = []
y = []
int_liposome = []
BG_liposome = []

for i in range(len(images[0])):
    tmp_frame = images[0][i]

    xy = pd.DataFrame(peak_local_max(tmp_frame, min_distance=8,threshold_abs=3000))
    x.extend(xy[0].tolist())
    y.extend(xy[1].tolist())

    for j in range(len(xy)):
        index = x[j],y[j]    
        int_liposome.append(cmask(index,tmp_frame))

    frame_list.extend([i]*len(xy))
    print "Frame: ", i, "of ",len(images[0])

features = pd.DataFrame(
        {'lip_int':int_liposome,
         'y'  : y,
         'x'  : x,
         'frame'  : frame_list})
```

Comment: The times between your first few prints of `Frame x of y` should tell you if it is the loading of the file that is costing you. Also, this looks simply parallelisable with multiprocessing - maybe you have 3 or 7 CPU cores doing nothing? Could it be done in greyscale to save processing R, G and B?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried profiling the code, say with `%prun` or `%lprun` in ipython? That'll tell you exactly where your slowdowns are occurring.

I can't make my own version of this without the tif stack, but I suspect the problem is the fact that you're using lists to store everything. Every time you do an append or an extension, python is having to allocate more memory. You could try getting the total count of maxima first, then allocating your output arrays, then rerunning to fill the arrays. Something like below

```
# run through once to get the count of local maxima
npeaks = (len(peak_local_max(f, min_distance=8, threshold_abs=3000))
          for f in images[0])
total_peaks = sum(npeaks)

# allocate storage arrays and rerun
x = np.zeros(total_peaks, np.float)
y = np.zeros_like(x)
int_liposome = np.zeros_like(x)
BG_liposome = np.zeros_like(x)

frame_list = np.zeros(total_peaks, np.int)
index_0 = 0
for frame_ind, tmp_frame in enumerate(images[0]):
    peaks = pd.DataFrame(peak_local_max(tmp_frame, min_distance=8,threshold_abs=3000))
    index_1 = index_0 + len(peaks)
    # copy the data from the DataFrame's underlying numpy array
    x[index_0:index_1] = peaks[0].values
    y[index_0:index_1] = peaks[1].values
    for i, peak in enumerate(peaks, index_0):
        int_liposome[i] = cmask(peak, tmp_frame)
    frame_list[index_0:index_1] = frame_ind
    # update the starting index
    index_0 = index_1
    print "Frame: ", frame_ind, "of ",len(images[0])
```

Comment: It might be simpler to create a list of lists (or Numpy arrays). The main list has one element per frame, which can be pre-allocated and indexed trivially.